# Analyzing core dump generated by multiple applications with gdb

Tags: gdb, coredump

I have a core dump generated by 2 applications -> /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/app1.
I know the dump can be analyzed by

```
    gdb /path/to/app /path/to/core
```

but is there a way to include both applications in the arguement?

I did try gdb '/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/app1' core.xxx but that doesnt seem right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot achieve what you want with a single invocation of `gdb`. But you could run `gdb` twice, in different terminal windows. I did that more than once, and it works quite well (except of course that your own brain could be slightly overloaded).

a `gdb` process can debug only one single program, with one single debugged process or (for post mortem debug) one single `core` file.

And a given `core` file is produced by abnormal termination of one single process (not several), so I don't understand your question.

Apparently, you have a crash in some execution of `python` probably augmented by your faulty C code. I suggest having a debuggable variant of Python, perhaps by installing the `python3-all-dbg` package or something similar, then use `gdb` on it. Of course, compile your C code plugged into Python with debugging enabled. Perhaps you violated some invariant of the Python garbage collector.

Comment: When I tried debugging the core file with gdb python core.xxx, I see a line in the debugger that says **core generated by '/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/app1'**. 
I took this to mean it was generated by 2 processes but I am beginning to think that app1 which happens to be a python process caused it to generate such a message.

Comment: No, `gdb` just shows you the entire command line (technically the `argv` array passed to `main` of Python) which faulted. Only one process produced the core dump.